# Changing .csv field separator using a PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm working on a script which will connect to an external FTP, download a .csv file and import each record from that .csv into a table.

I've written a script successfully to do so, however I have one major issue. One of the columns in the .csv file is a Description column which, you guessed it, contains commas.

This description column is wrapped in quotation marks (") which I've read could be a solution, however the column also contains measurements, so I'd have to escape the " as well.

The easiest solution that I could see to this would be to change the field separator to something uncommon, such as a | or a ^. Can anyone tell me if this is something that can be accomplished in my PHP script? If anyone has an alternate suggestion, please let me know, any direction here would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Quotes within a quoted string can be escaped with an additional character such as `\`` or even another `"`.... and PHP's [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) method accepts this `escape` character as an additional argument

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mark. I'm using ftp_fget() to get the file currently. Can I use fgetcsv() to connect to an ftp server and get a file?

Comment: No, `fgetcsv()` is used to read a line from a csv file.... the `import` part of what you're doing

Comment: Thanks again. Just to check, with `fgetcsv()`, would I need to put my escape character into the .csv in the correct locations manually? My issue here is that I have >50,000 records in the .csv, so it's not going to be an option.

Comment: If the external CSV file that you're reading is badly formed, then you're going to have real problems.... the only solution is to get whoever generates that external file to create it properly

Comment: Yeah I was afraid that was going to be the answer. Thanks for your help Mark.

Comment: Take a look at `str_getcsv()`. You can use that if you're reading the file into strings.